# xUnit Test - Type or Namespace ' ' could not be found

Tags: c#, xunit

I'm pretty new to programming and started watching Scott Allen's C# fundamentals at Pluralsight. I hit a roadblock with xUnit Testing. When trying to retrieve a class on the testing proj it kept on saying that the class type or namespace could not be found.
I already added a reference from the testing proj to the main proj and made sure that they target the same framework but I'm still getting the same error.

*Tried adding using Gradebook; / GradeBook; on the testing file but it's greyed out.*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Gradebook\Gradebook.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Testing file:**

```
using Xunit;

namespace GradeBook.Tests
{
    public class BookTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var book = new Book(""); /// **'Book' type or namespace could not be found**
        }
    }
}
```

**Book.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
    
namespace Gradebook
{
    partial class Program
    {    
        public class Book
        {  
            //Initializes grade field and labels the list with unique name.
    
            private List<double> grades;
            private string name;
    
            public Book(string name)
            {    
                grades = new List<double>();
                this.name = name;    
            }    
    
            public void AddGrade(double grade)
            {
                grades.Add(grade);
            }  
    
            //shows the average grade, highest/lowest grade in a Book.
    
            public Statistics GetStatistics() 
            {
                Statistics result = new Statistics();
    
                result.Average = 0.0;
    
                result.High = double.MinValue;
                result.Low = double.MaxValue;  
    
                foreach (double grade in grades)
                {    
                    result.High = Math.Max(grade, result.High);
                    result.Low = Math.Min(grade, result.High);
    
                    result.Average += grade;  
                }
    
                result.Average /= grades.Count;
    
                return result;  
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's possible that you need to add a using on top of your test file. p.e. using GradeBook; so the compiler can find where the Book class. Also, if you upload to github, you should to upload the source code, not a rar file. There are plenty of tutorials about getting started with git / github

Comment: Yeah i also tried adding using Gradebook; on the test file but it's greyed out and yea I should've read about github first but this problem is already getting into me, kinda frustrating that I wasn't able to resolve this problem today. I wanted to continue to learn c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `Book` class **INSIDE** the `Program` class.

Move ALL classes inside the `Program` outside the `partial Program class` and places under the `namespace Gradebook`.

Comment: o...m...g i am an idiot. I just tried removing the partial program class instead , Gradebook; worked and no longer greyed out. But I never knew that it was safe to remove the partial program class though. I'm still learning so thank you for the help Max!